# How to write lambda expression with EventHandler javafx

Tags: java, javafx, lambda, expression, eventhandler

I'm trying to rewrite this code

```
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.hashCode());
    }
};
```

as

```
new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(e -> System.out.println(e.hashCode()));
```

and I get errors. What is my mistake here?

Comment: The lambda equivalent of the first code block is just `event -> System.out.println(event.hashCode())` (without the call to a constructor, which is I think what you are trying to do).

Comment: in simple words it is the entire `functional interface` that you replace with lambda and not the function within the interface. The lambda equivalent of ur first code snippet is `event -> System.out.println(e.hashCode())`. What you are doing is basically adding "lambda" in constructor. Invalid

Comment: @Pascal Hoffenheimer if the answer satisfies you, you may accept it, it's how a forum works, if you didn't, people with same problem won't come see the solution because the post would appear as "unsolved"

Comment: I understand my mistakes:

1. Constructor is to be left out.
2. Use parameter name. Don't rename it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lambda expression is here to replace the whole `FunctionalInterface` and not only its method, so it's not `constructor + lambda` but only `lambda` :

1. Use the `EventHandler` as parameter :

   ```
   someNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                           new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                              @Override
                              public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                                 System.out.println(event.hashCode());
                              }
                           });
   ```

   Becomes **:**

   ```
    someNode.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, 
                             event ->  System.out.println(event.hashCode()));
   ```

---

2. Use the `EventHandler` in a variable :

   ```
   EventHandler<MouseEvent> eh = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                                          System.out.println(event.hashCode());
                                      }
                               };
   ```

   It'll become :

   ```
   EventHandler<MouseEvent> eh = e -> System.out.println(e.hashCode());
   ```

---

---

It's exists various way to use lambda, with or without parameter, like :

```
Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Here");
```

Comment: Assume am not going to use the event parameter at all, Any way I can just drop it or any special variable name (_) like in Kotlin?

Comment: @mahemadhi not in this case, because the method of `EventHandler` does have a parameter, but for a Supplier/Runnable/... you can (see edit)

Comment: Am sorry to confuse you.. It's just another question